# Redirect loop with internal elastic load balancer (between varnish & www node)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, varnish, amazon-vpc

I've got a website & the scheme is the following:

Internet<-->ExternalELB<-->Varnish<-->WWWnode

I'm trying to setup a second InternalELB so the scheme would change to:

Internet<-->ExternalELB<-->Varnish<-->InternalELB<-->WWWnode

But when I apply the new config, I get 301 endless loop on the frontend! :(

What could be the problem?

The WWWnode doesn't have any https certificates installed, it uses only 80 port & the ExternalELB passes traffic from 443 & 80 to just 80 on a Varnish node.

Comment: Which server generates the redirect?  It isn't the ELB doing that.  Verify in yout server logs.

Comment: It was a WWWnode which needed the following code in nginx config:
`# for Internal ELB to work correctly
#
fastcgi_param  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
#
fastcgi_param  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT 443;`